# A maximal inequality for sample variance

Tags: pr.probability

I work with i.i.d. variables $X_1, \dots, X_{N}$ such that $0 \le X_i \le 1$, $E[X_i] = \mu$, $\operatorname{Var}[X_i] = \sigma^2$.

I am gradually sampling $X_1, X_2, \dots$ and want to ensure that the natural sample variance estimate stays within reasonable bounds. More formally, define $A_n = \sum_{i = 1}^n (X_i - \bar X_n)^2 - (n-1)\sigma^2$ where $\bar X_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} X_i/n$. We have $E[A_n] = 0$ for every $n$. Also, using that $X_i$s are bounded, we can crudely upper bound the variance as $\operatorname{Var}[A_n] \le n\sigma^2$.

Using Chebyshev's inequality, we can conclude that $P[|A_{N}| > 100\sqrt{N\sigma^2}] < 0.5$. However, I would like to have a stronger result $P[\max_{n = 1}^{N} |A_{n}| > 100\sqrt{N\sigma^2}] < 0.5$. My question is: How do we achieve this bound? Is there some well-known inequality that proves this?

Note that if $A_n$ was a martingale, we could use Kolmogorov's inequality to arrive at this conclusion. My intuition why the inequality holds is that $A_n$ behaves very similar to a martingale.

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Comment: @IosifPinelis No, it's perfect! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}$Note that
\begin{equation*}
    A_n=B_n-C_n,
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    B_n:=\sum_1^n Y_i,\quad C_n:=\frac1n\,\Big(\sum_1^n Z_i\Big)^2-\si^2,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    Z_i:=X_i-\mu,\quad Y_i:=Z_i^2-\si^2. 
\end{equation*}
Note also that, in view of the condition $0\le X_i\le1$ and excluding the trivial case with $\si^2=0$,
\begin{equation*}
\si:=\sqrt{\si^2}\in(0,1/2].    \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
So, for any integer $N\ge1$, letting
\begin{equation*}
    y:=10\si\sqrt N,\quad z:=90\si\sqrt N,\quad x:=y+z=100\si\sqrt N,  \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}
we get
\begin{equation*}
z\ge\si^2   \tag{30}\label{30}
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    P(\max_1^N|A_n|>x)\le Q_1+Q_2, \tag{40}\label{40}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    Q_1:=P(\max_1^N|B_n|>y)
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    Q_2:=P(\max_1^N|C_n|>z)=P(\max_1^N C_n>z), 
\end{equation*}
because $-C_n\le\si^2\le z$ for all $n$, by \eqref{30}.

By Kolmogorov's maximal inequality and \eqref{20},
\begin{equation*}
    Q_1\le\frac{EB_N^2}{y^2}=\frac{N\,EY_1^2}{y^2}\le\frac{N\si^2}{y^2}=\frac1{100}, 
\end{equation*}
because $EY_1^2\le EZ_1^4\le EZ_1^2=\si^2$.

To bound $Q_2$, we use the following simple but crucial construction:
let
\begin{equation*}
    D_n:=C_n+\si^2+\si^2(H_N-H_n),
\end{equation*}
where $H_n:=\sum_1^n\frac1k$. Noting that
\begin{equation*}
    C_n-C_{n-1}
    =-\frac1{n(n-1)}\,\Big(\sum_1^{n-1}Z_i\Big)^2+\frac{Z_n^2}n+\frac{2Z_n}n\,\sum_1^{n-1}Z_i \\ 
    \le\frac{Z_n^2}n+\frac{2Z_n}n\,\sum_1^{n-1}Z_i, 
\end{equation*}
we see that $(D_n)_1^N$ is a nonnegative supermartingale with respect to the filtration generated by the $X_i$'s (or, equivalently, by the $Z_i$'s). Therefore (see e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/360580/96609) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/360632/96609)),
\begin{equation*}
    Q_2\le P(\max_1^N D_n>z)\le\frac{ED_1}z=\frac{\si^2 H_N}{90\si\sqrt N}<\frac1{100},
\end{equation*}
in view of \eqref{20}, \eqref{10}, and inequality $\dfrac{H_N}{\sqrt N}\le\dfrac{H_2}{\sqrt2}<1.07$ for integers $N\ge1$.

Thus, by \eqref{40},
\begin{equation*}
    P(\max_1^N|A_n|>100\si\sqrt N)<\frac2{100}<0.5.\quad\Box
\end{equation*}